# Google Map API V3 : How to Add or Display InfoWindow() to Marker in CS page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This my first question and I hope it's in correct formatting :)
I am trying to build application in ASP.NET,C# 
which retrieve coordinate (Lat,Lon) from SQL and display it as markers (it's Done ) but when I try to add infowindow() to those markers the maps not showing 
I need to display infowindw() to each marker 
 this is my code in CS page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string markers = GetMarkers();
    Literal1.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
 function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.43242, -89.209343),
 zoom: 5,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('pic/marker.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30, 42));
 var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapArea'),
 mapOptions);"


+ markers + @"}
 </script>";
}

protected string GetMarkers()
{
    string markers = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=web1;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Lat, Lan FROM Location", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            i++;
            markers +=
            @"var marker" + i.ToString() + @" = new google.maps.Marker({ icon: image,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + reader["Lat"].ToString() + ", " +
            reader["Lan"].ToString() + ")," +
            @"map: myMap});";
        }
    }
    return markers;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.  I use a string builder then set Literal.Text to the output.  This particular example uses MarkerCluster which is located here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Good luck.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");

        sb.Append("var mapOpts = {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};");
        sb.Append("var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"map\"), mapOpts);");
        sb.Append("var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();");
        sb.Append("var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();");
        sb.Append("var markerArray = [];");

        sb.Append("function makeMarker(options){var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});");
        sb.Append("pushPin.setOptions(options);");
        sb.Append("google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, \"click\", function(){");
        sb.Append("infoWindow.setOptions(options);infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);});");
        sb.Append("markerBounds.extend(options.position);markerArray.push(pushPin);");
        sb.Append("return pushPin;}");

        sb.Append("google.maps.event.addListener(map, \"click\", function(){infoWindow.close();});");

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("makeMarker({title: \"" + (string)dr["GEO_FORMATTED_NAME"].ToString());
            sb.Append("\",position: new google.maps.LatLng(");
            sb.Append((string)dr["GEO_LAT"].ToString() + ", " + (string)dr["GEO_LONG"].ToString() + "),");
            sb.Append("content:\"<table>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td class='fls'>Title:&nbsp;&nbsp;" + (string)dr["OBJ_TITLE"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
            sb.Append("</table>\"});");
        }

        sb.Append("map.fitBounds(markerBounds);");

        sb.Append("var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);");

        sb.Append("</script>");
```

Comment: Dear SQLDBA thanks for support , but when i try to add DataTable which you add it as  an object in your code "dt".
can't do this correctly it's give me error.

I want only add infowindo() in while() statement
i will appreciated if you do like this